# PowerBuilder PowerScript Selecting More than one option from a dropdown

Tags: powerbuilder

I am having a great amount of difficulty wrapping my head around this concept:  We currently present our reps with a drop down menu on the order screen that will present them with multiple add-on options depending on the product added to the order in the line before.  The issue lies where they can only choose one of the options, and the line item gets written to the order and the reps are then unable to select the second add-on to add to the order (in the case that the customer wanted both add-ons instead of just one).  The code posted below is the work of the programmer that came before me, so I am not sure if it is well written as Powerscript is new to me.

Caveats -- this must remain a dropdown, and I cannot simply add the second add-on in the background.  In order for the orders system to work properly, the selected addons must come right after the main product, one after another.  I also cannot add a "bundled" product, as that would mess with sales reporting.

```
String contact_type, contact_name 
Long contact_no, ll_child_row
long product_no, addon_product_no
string addon
string null_string
string promo_key
string addon_edition_code
int qty
real price
DataWindowChild contact_child 
AcceptText()

If GetColumnName() = 'attn_freeform' Then 
    AcceptText()
    GetChild('attn_freeform', contact_child)
    ll_child_row = contact_child.GetRow()
    If ll_child_row > 0 Then
        contact_name = contact_child.GetItemString(ll_child_row, 'contact_name')
        If data = contact_name Then 
            contact_type = contact_child.GetItemString(ll_child_row, 'tar_contact_type')
            contact_no = contact_child.GetItemNumber(ll_child_row, 'tar_contact_no')
            SetItem(row, "ship2_tar_contact_type", contact_type)
            SetItem(row, "ship2_tar_contact_no", contact_no)
        Else
            SetItem(row, "ship2_tar_contact_type", '')
            SetItem(row, "ship2_tar_contact_no", -1)
        End If
    Else
        SetItem(row, "ship2_tar_contact_type", '')
        SetItem(row, "ship2_tar_contact_no", -1)
    End If      
End If 

if GetColumnName() = 'quantity' and not isnull(dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row,"name_1")) then
    SetItem(row + 1,"quantity",integer(data))
    AcceptText()
end if 
if GetColumnName() = 'package_no' and not isnull(dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row,"name_1")) then
    SetItem(row + 1,"package_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"package_no"))
    AcceptText()
end if 
if GetColumnName() = 'attn_freeform' and not isnull(dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row,"name_1")) then
    SetItem(row + 1,"attn_freeform",data)
    AcceptText()
end if 
if GetColumnName() = 'promo_key' and not isnull(dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row,"name_1")) then
    SetItem(row + 1,"promo_key",data)
    AcceptText()
end if 
if GetColumnName() = 'order_type' and not isnull(dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row,"name_1")) then
    SetItem(row + 1,"order_type",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"order_type"))
end if 

if GetColumnName() = 'product_no' and not isnull(dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row,"name_1")) then
    SetNull(null_string)
    dw_order_detail.deleterow(row + 1)
    dw_order_detail.SetItem(row,"name_1",null_string)
end if  

product_no = 0
if GetColumnName() = 'product_no' and isnull(dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row,"name_1")) then 
product_no = dw_order_detail.GetItemNumber(row,'product_no')
int checkAddon
Select isnull(count(*),0) into :checkAddon From  product p JOIN mag_addons t ON p.edition_code = t.primary_edition and p.product_no = :product_no;
    if checkAddon > 0 then
        dw_order_detail.SetItem(row, "teach_12",0)
    end if
end if 

promo_key = dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"promo_key")  
qty = dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"quantity")
AcceptText()

if GetColumnName() = 'name_1'  then //the dropdown for addon selection appears here
    long ll_row, ll_inserted_row
    SetNull(null_string)
    product_no = 0
    product_no = dw_order_detail.GetItemNumber(row,'product_no')
    addon = dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row,"name_1") //this sets the name of the addon
if isnull(addon) or addon = "Select Add On..."  then 
    return
end if 
Select p.product_no, t.add_on_edition into :addon_product_no, :addon_edition_code from product p JOIN mag_addons t ON p.edition_code = t.add_on_edition and p.description = :addon JOIN product d ON t.primary_edition = d.edition_code;
if row + 1  <  dw_order_detail.RowCount() then 
     if dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row + 1,'addondesc') = addon then
        return
    end if 
end if 
if product_no >= 1 then 
    SELECT price INTO :price FROM dbo.get_price(:promo_key,:addon_edition_code,:qty, :vg_project_id);
    if price = 0 then 
        price = .99 
    end if
    ll_row = dw_order_detail.GetRow()
    ll_inserted_row = dw_order_detail.InsertRow(row + 1)
    SetItem(row + 1,"order_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"order_no"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"line_item_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"line_item_no") + 1)
    SetItem(row + 1,"status_code",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"status_code"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"ship2_tar_contact_type",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"ship2_tar_contact_type"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"ship2_tar_contact_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"ship2_tar_contact_no"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"attn_freeform",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"attn_freeform"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"promo_key",promo_key)
    SetItem(row + 1,"product_no",addon_product_no)
    SetItem(row + 1,"quantity",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"quantity"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"price",price)
    SetItem(row + 1,"price_1",price)
    SetItem(row + 1,"package_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"package_no"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"order_type",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"order_type"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"shipping_rate",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"shipping_rate"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"sales_tax_rate",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"sales_tax_rate"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"ship2_tar_acct_type",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"ship2_tar_acct_type"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"ship2_tar_acct_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"ship2_tar_acct_no"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"jt_id",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"jt_id"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"year_began_teach",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"year_began_teach"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"preferred_email",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"preferred_email"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"email",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"email"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"addondesc",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"name_1"))
    SetItem(row,"teach_12",1)
    SetItem(row + 1,"teach_12",2)

    dw_order_detail.AcceptText()
end if
dw_order_detail.ScrollToRow(ll_inserted_row)
dw_order_detail.SetFocus()
end if
dw_order_detail.AcceptText()
```

Comment: What event is this from?

Comment: It's been a while since I did Powerbuilder. But I seem to remember that you can use a dropdowndatawindow and put any datawindow in it you want. I think you could create a datawindow with a checkbox on each row and then put it as the dropdown.

Comment: @MattBalent it is from the `itemchanged` event

Comment: Accepttext within the itemchanged event does nothing so you can remove all of those.  You should be using dwo.name property and not 'GetColumnName()' method.

Comment: I understand removing the `accepttext` which is fine, but the `dwo.name` property does not exist, in the Sybase PowerBuilder 11.5 documentation it recommends using `dwo.GetColumnName`

Comment: In the itemchanged event for a datawindow (even in 11.5) there are three parameters: row, dwo, and data.  If you don't have these then you are not in the itemchanged event.

Comment: Yes, I have those three parameters and I can confirm I am in the `itemchanged` event, but `.name` is producing an error `Incompatible property name for type dw_order_detail`

Comment: Nevermind, I assumed `dwo` was generic and correlated to `dw_order_detail` when it is simply `dwo`

Comment: Unfortunately this still does not help figure out how to add the ability to select a second addon product instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

After much headache and rewriting code, I was able to create a SQL product that I considered a bundle of both add-on products, and used the code in PowerBuilder to check for those bundled products and then insert a separate line item for each.  I did hard code some of it, as it needed to be done ASAP, so if anyone has any ideas for prettier, more efficient non-hard-coded script please let me know.

All changes occur in the `itemchanged()` event:

```
String contact_type, contact_name 
Long contact_no, ll_child_row
long product_no, addon_product_no
string addon
string null_string
string promo_key
string addon_edition_code
int qty
real price
long product_no_1, product_no_2, add_on_edition_1, add_on_edition_2
int cnt
string addondesc_1, addondesc_2
DataWindowChild contact_child 

AcceptText()
If GetColumnName() = 'attn_freeform' Then 
    AcceptText()
    GetChild('attn_freeform', contact_child)
    ll_child_row = contact_child.GetRow()
    If ll_child_row > 0 Then
        contact_name = contact_child.GetItemString(ll_child_row, 'contact_name')
    If data = contact_name Then 
        contact_type = contact_child.GetItemString(ll_child_row, 'tar_contact_type')
        contact_no = contact_child.GetItemNumber(ll_child_row, 'tar_contact_no')
        SetItem(row, "ship2_tar_contact_type", contact_type)
        SetItem(row, "ship2_tar_contact_no", contact_no)
    Else
        SetItem(row, "ship2_tar_contact_type", '')
        SetItem(row, "ship2_tar_contact_no", -1)
    End If
Else
    SetItem(row, "ship2_tar_contact_type", '')
    SetItem(row, "ship2_tar_contact_no", -1)
    End If      
End If 

if GetColumnName() = 'quantity' and not isnull(dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row,"name_1")) then
    SetItem(row + 1,"quantity",integer(data))
    AcceptText()
end if 
if GetColumnName() = 'package_no' and not isnull(dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row,"name_1")) then
    SetItem(row + 1,"package_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"package_no"))
    AcceptText()
end if 
if GetColumnName() = 'attn_freeform' and not isnull(dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row,"name_1")) then
    SetItem(row + 1,"attn_freeform",data)
    AcceptText()
end if 
if GetColumnName() = 'promo_key' and not isnull(dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row,"name_1")) then
    SetItem(row + 1,"promo_key",data)
    AcceptText()
end if 
if GetColumnName() = 'order_type' and not isnull(dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row,"name_1")) then
    SetItem(row + 1,"order_type",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"order_type"))
end if 

if GetColumnName() = 'product_no' and not isnull(dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row,"name_1")) then
    SetNull(null_string)
    dw_order_detail.deleterow(row + 1)
    dw_order_detail.SetItem(row,"name_1",null_string)
end if  

product_no = 0
if GetColumnName() = 'product_no' and isnull(dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row,"name_1")) then 
    product_no = dw_order_detail.GetItemNumber(row,'product_no')
    int checkAddon 
    Select isnull(count(*),0) into :checkAddon From  product p JOIN TARDIS_Magazine_AddOns t ON p.edition_code = t.primary_edition and p.product_no = :product_no;
    //sets a new dropdown for addons if they exist
    if checkAddon > 0 then
        dw_order_detail.SetItem(row, "teach_12",0)
    end if
end if 

promo_key = dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"promo_key")  
qty = dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"quantity")
AcceptText()
if GetColumnName() = 'name_1' then 
    long ll_row, ll_inserted_row
    SetNull(null_string)
    product_no = 0
    product_no = dw_order_detail.GetItemNumber(row,'product_no')
    addon = dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row,"name_1")
    if isnull(addon) or addon = "Select Add On..."  then 
        return
    end if 
    //do this once for one addon as normal
    if addon <> 'SS + GS 3-6' and addon <> 'SS + GS 3-6 TE' then
        Select p.product_no, t.add_on_edition into :addon_product_no, :addon_edition_code from product p JOIN TARDIS_Magazine_AddOns t ON p.edition_code = t.add_on_edition and p.description = :addon JOIN product d ON t.primary_edition = d.edition_code;
    elseif addon = 'SS + GS 3-6' then
        product_no_1 = 2576
        product_no_2 = 2579
        add_on_edition_1 = 304
        add_on_edition_2 = 314
        addondesc_1 = 'ScienceSpin 3-6'
        addondesc_2 = 'Geography Spin 3-6'
    elseif addon = 'SS + GS 3-6 TE' then
        product_no_1 = 2577
        product_no_2 = 2580
        add_on_edition_1 = 305
        add_on_edition_2 = 315
        addondesc_1 = 'ScienceSpin 3-6 TE'
        addondesc_2 = 'Geography Spin 3-6 TE'
    end if  
    if row + 1  <  dw_order_detail.RowCount() then 
        if dw_order_detail.GetItemString(row + 1,'addondesc') = addon then
            return
        end if 
    end if
    //the following condition should be executed once as normal if there is only one addon
    if addon <> 'SS + GS 3-6' and addon <> 'SS + GS 3-6 TE' then
    if product_no >= 1 then 
        SELECT price INTO :price FROM dbo.get_price(:promo_key,:addon_edition_code,:qty, :vg_project_id);
        if price = 0 then 
            price = .99 
        end if
    ll_row = dw_order_detail.GetRow()
    //the following line inserts a row
    ll_inserted_row = dw_order_detail.InsertRow(row + 1)
    //the following lines set the data into each field on the row
    SetItem(row + 1,"order_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"order_no"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"line_item_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"line_item_no") + 1)
    SetItem(row + 1,"status_code",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"status_code"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"ship2_tar_contact_type",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"ship2_tar_contact_type"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"ship2_tar_contact_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"ship2_tar_contact_no"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"attn_freeform",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"attn_freeform"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"promo_key",promo_key)
    SetItem(row + 1,"product_no",addon_product_no)
    SetItem(row + 1,"quantity",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"quantity"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"price",price)
    SetItem(row + 1,"price_1",price)
    SetItem(row + 1,"package_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"package_no"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"order_type",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"order_type"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"shipping_rate",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"shipping_rate"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"sales_tax_rate",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"sales_tax_rate"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"ship2_tar_acct_type",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"ship2_tar_acct_type"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"ship2_tar_acct_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"ship2_tar_acct_no"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"jt_id",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"jt_id"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"year_began_teach",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"year_began_teach"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"preferred_email",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"preferred_email"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"email",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"email"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"addondesc",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"name_1"))
    SetItem(row,"teach_12",1)
    SetItem(row + 1,"teach_12",2)


    dw_order_detail.AcceptText()
    end if
else
    if product_no_1 = 2576 or product_no_1 = 2577 then 
        SELECT price INTO :price FROM dbo.get_price(:promo_key,:add_on_edition_1,:qty, :vg_project_id);
        if price = 0 then 
            price = .99 
        end if
    elseif product_no_2 = 2579 or product_no_2 = 2580 then
        SELECT price INTO :price FROM dbo.get_price(:promo_key,:add_on_edition_2,:qty, :vg_project_id);
        if price = 0 then 
            price = .99 
        end if
   end if
FOR cnt = 1 to 2
    ll_row = dw_order_detail.GetRow()
    //the following line inserts a row
    ll_inserted_row = dw_order_detail.InsertRow(row + 1)
    //the following lines set the data into each field on the row
    SetItem(row + 1,"order_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"order_no"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"line_item_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"line_item_no") + 1)
    SetItem(row + 1,"status_code",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"status_code"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"ship2_tar_contact_type",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"ship2_tar_contact_type"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"ship2_tar_contact_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"ship2_tar_contact_no"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"attn_freeform",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"attn_freeform"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"promo_key",promo_key)
    if cnt = 1 then
        SetItem(row + 1,"product_no",add_on_edition_1)
    else 
        SetItem(row + 1,"product_no",add_on_edition_2)
    end if
    SetItem(row + 1,"quantity",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"quantity"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"price",price)
    SetItem(row + 1,"price_1",price)
    SetItem(row + 1,"package_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"package_no"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"order_type",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"order_type"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"shipping_rate",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"shipping_rate"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"sales_tax_rate",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"sales_tax_rate"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"ship2_tar_acct_type",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"ship2_tar_acct_type"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"ship2_tar_acct_no",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"ship2_tar_acct_no"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"jt_id",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"jt_id"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"year_began_teach",dw_order_detail.getitemnumber(row,"year_began_teach"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"preferred_email",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"preferred_email"))
    SetItem(row + 1,"email",dw_order_detail.getitemstring(row,"email"))
    if cnt = 1 then
        SetItem(row + 1,"addondesc",addondesc_1)
    else
        SetItem(row + 1,"addondesc",addondesc_2)
    end if
    SetItem(row,"teach_12",1)
    SetItem(row + 1,"teach_12",2)
    dw_order_detail.AcceptText()
NEXT
end if
dw_order_detail.ScrollToRow(ll_inserted_row)
dw_order_detail.SetFocus()
end if
dw_order_detail.AcceptText()
```